# When's the next snapshot?

Tags: snapshot

I'm currently only interested in holding my iotas, not in running a full node, developing, or transacting.

Is there an email newsletter I could subscribe to that will only notify me when there's a change (for example, a snapshot or update) that requires me to claim my iotas?

Is there a website (URL) that only lists the history of such changes?

I'd rather not use Slack or sign up for another forum. I'm just looking for something minimal & simple.

Comment: That's not a very precise indication what you're looking for. Neither for events nor for ways of informing you.

Comment: How is it not precise? I want to get an email every time there's a change that requires me to claim my iotas. And, I want to be able to go to a website to see a historical list of such changes.

Comment: The best way I know is to subscribe to the [RSS feed of the IOTA blog](https://blog.iota.org/feed) but currently the signal to noise ratio is quite low due to all the partnership announcements and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use slack, the better option to keep you aware of last official announcements is to follow @iotatoken on twitter.